# Prove $\text{Li}_2(e^{-2 i x})+\text{Li}_2(e^{2 i x})=\frac{1}{3} (6 x^2-6 \pi x+\pi ^2)$ when $0<x<\pi$

Tags: special-functions, polylogarithm

This is an identity I deduced when playing with the initial-boundary value problem of heat conduction equation asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189706/1871). It's easy to verify numerically with *Mathematica*:

```
Plot[{PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)], 
  1/3 (π^2 - 6 π x + 6 x^2)}, {x, -1, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, *Mathematica* doesn't know how to simplify $\text{Li}_2(e^{-2 i x})+\text{Li}_2(e^{2 i x})$ to $\frac{1}{3} (6 x^2-6 \pi  x+\pi ^2)$ symbolically, so I'm wondering, how can I prove it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{-2\ic x}} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{2\ic x}}\,\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ x\ <\ \pi}} =
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\exp\pars{2\pi\ic\,{x \over \pi}}} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\exp\pars{-2\pi\ic\,{x \over \pi}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{2} \over 2!}\,\mathrm{B}_{2}\pars{x \over \pi}
\end{align}

> which is [Jonqui$\grave{\mrm{e}}$re Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions). $\ds{\mrm{B}_{n}}$ is a [Bernoulli Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).
>   
>   Note that $\ds{\mrm{B}_{2}\pars{z} = z^{2} - z + {1 \over 6}}$ such that

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{-2\ic x}} +
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{2\ic x}}\,\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ x\ <\ \pi}} =
2\pi^{2}\bracks{\pars{x \over \pi}^{2} - {x \over \pi} + {1 \over 6}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{2x^{2} - 2\pi x + {\pi^{2} \over 3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-2 i x})+\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{2 i x})\\
=2\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{2i x})\\
=2\operatorname{Sl}_2(2x)\\
=2(\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\pi x+x^2)$$
Where $\operatorname{Sl}$ is the [SL-type Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Comment: Most of this is just definitions, the only property that's used is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Bernoulli_polynomials). Pretty simple. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try a series expansion around $x=0$ and get 
$$\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-2 i x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i x}\right)=\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-2 \pi  x+2 x^2+O\left(x^{99}\right)$$

Comment: Er… how to calculate the series expansion of LHS?

Comment: @xzczd. Ask Mathematica to do it ... and let me know if it works ! Cheers

Comment: OK… _Mathematica_ can't find the general form of the series coefficient, `SeriesCoefficient[PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)], {x, 0, n}]` returns the input, but e.g. `Simplify[Series[PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)], {x, 0, 10}] // Normal, 0 < x < Pi]` returns `1/3 (Pi^2 - 6 Pi x + 6 x^2)`, so the identity is verified in another way. Thx.

Comment: @xzczd. Coulod you try the first instruction not with $n$ but with $6$ for example ? Thanks to let me know. I suppose that you need to assume $x>0$.

Comment: OK ! Try *Series* instead of *SeriesCoefficient* still with $6$ and not $n$. I think that I had things like that years ago when I had Mma at university.

Comment: With the assumption added, e.g. `SeriesCoefficient[PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)], {x, 0, #}, Assumptions -> x > 0] & /@ Range[0, 10]` successfully returns `{Pi^2/3, -2 Pi, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. `SeriesCoefficient[PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)], {x, 0, n}, 
 Assumptions -> x > 0]` still returns the input, though.

Comment: @xzczd. I am sure that the problem is $n$.

Comment: I tend to consider it as the limitation of `SeriesCoefficient`, it can calculate general series coefficient in some cases, e.g. `SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}]` returns `Piecewise[{{1/n!, n >= 0}}, 0]`.